# Mount-DiskImage not recognized cmdlet

Tags: powershell, iso-image

Here on Win 7 64x I'm trying to mount an ISO using PowerShell.
I have tried several versions of syntax, but they all failed.

```
PowerShell Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Users\win7\Desktop\IsoFiles\IMPORTEDDATA.iso"
```

on this I get:

> a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DiskImage'

What is the correct syntax to mount this ISO?

Comment: Update your question to indicate which version of PowerShell you currently have installed.

Comment: Can you run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and update your question.  Provide a screenshot of the output of that command, and the error message after running the command you ran in the same window, just provide a link to the screenshot within the body of your question.   I will be unable to update my answer without this information.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PowerShell are you running?
What is in your...

```
$env:Path
$env:PSModulePath
```

The help files provide you with your answer.

[Mount-Disk​Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/mount-diskimage?view=win10-ps)

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Mount-DiskImage).Parameters
Get-help -Name Mount-DiskImage -Full
Get-help -Name Mount-DiskImage -Online
Get-help -Name Mount-DiskImage -Examples
```

> Examples
>
> Example 1: Mounting an ISO
>
> Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "E:\ISO-Files\My US Visit Fall 2010 Pictures.iso"
>
> This example mounts an ISO by specifying the image path.

So, compared to your command, it looks fine, so, something else is a miss on your system.

```
# Get parameter that accepts pipeline input
Get-Help Mount-DiskImage -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select * 

# Get cmdlet / function parameter aliases
(Get-Command Mount-DiskImage).Parameters.Values | 
where aliases | 
select Name, Aliases | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Alias results for a given cmdlet or function.'
```